# EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION when extending UIView

Tags: ios, swift, ios8

I'm trying to create my own custom view class for a keyboard I'm playing around with for iOS8 and when I create a new class that extends `UIView` I crash with the `Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP,subcode=0x0)` error when the loading the keyboard. The error is shown on the line `class KeyButton: UIView {`, and I'm struggling to debug this much further. I was originally trying to extend `UIButton` but that didn't work so I changed it to `UIView` with no further luck.

I know there will be a few teething issues with Swift/iOS8, but hopefully this is fixable!

**Edit**

Full class code:

```
import UIKit

class KeyButton: UIView { /* This is where the app crashes, apparently */

    init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        // Initialization code
    }

    /*
    // Only override drawRect: if you perform custom drawing.
    // An empty implementation adversely affects performance during animation.
    override func drawRect(rect: CGRect)
    {
        // Drawing code
    }
    */

}
```

Comment: Can you show us some code? It's hard to diagnoze the problem without looking at its source.

Comment: I made a new Cocoa Touch Class, had it extend `UIView` and then dragged a `UIView` into my keyboard's nib and changed the class to `KeyButton`. Having the view within the main nib as a `UIView` does not crash the app, whilst having it as `keyButton` crashes the app with the above error. No code has been modified, but I'll post the full code for the class

Comment: Strange... Can you also post the backtrace?

Comment: There's nothing but `(lldb)` in the console (debugging extensions has been fun!), but I think I've got the backtrace, highlighted on the part it crashes at https://www.dropbox.com/s/8xmylpptdhvpk7w/Screenshot%202014-06-04%2016.02.15.png

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had a similar issue recently, but figured it out. As it turns out, in iOS 8, but not iOS 7, `initWithCoder` (in Objective-C) is required. All you have to do is add the following to your class:

```
init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder!)
{
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
}
```

I hope that helps!

Comment: This may solve the problem with it being created using a nib, but I've moved on to creating it via code (`let customButton: KeyButton = KeyButton.buttonWithType(UIButtonType.System) as KeyButton`), which still crashes. It's hard to know what the issue is because when it crashes it doesn't give a useful error (just says it was interrupted). If another answer doesn't come along I'll test this and mark as correct if it is.

Comment: Sorry, site was in read-only mode. This does indeed fix the problem, thanks! How odd.